# Why is debug-on-error always enabled at startup?

Tags: debugging, start-up, debug-on-error

Whenever I start up emacs, debug-on-error is enabled.  I can't figure out why, there's nowhere where I explicitly enable it.  Is there any way for me to figure out where it's coming from?

Comment: Try `M-x rgrep` over your config.  It's probably happening in some package you've installed.  Failing that, do the same in your server's `site-lisp` directory.

Comment: Bisect your init file to find the culprit. Some code you're loading is setting it to non-`nil`.

Comment: @phils you know what?  I found it.  I thought I had tried that before but maybe I missed this instance: https://github.com/emacsmirror/powershell-mode/blob/master/powershell-mode.el#L32

Comment: You could log an upstream bug report for that if there isn't one already.  Or try an alternative version.  I'm assuming it's this?  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PowerShell#h5o-2

Answer (score 2):

If your `Emacs` is launched with `--debug-init` command line arg, then `debug-on-error` is set to `startup` for the duration of the init process, and reset subsequently.

---

The  easiest way to catch the culprit is to do this ....

Go to your [Early Init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Early-Init-File.html), and right the top add the following snippet

```lisp
(add-variable-watcher
 'debug-on-error
 (defun someone-is-setting-debug-on-error (symbol newval operation where)
   (when newval
     (message "Some one is setting `debug-on-error' to %S [%S]" newval load-file-name)
     (debug))))
```

and restart emacs.

That way the stacktrace will hopefully give you a clue about what is happening, or confirm your hunch.

Without you telling us what `Emacs` you are using---spacemacs, doomemacs---etc, it is difficult to  guess how your initialization process is setup---whether it loads single file, or loads multiple files etc.